# xmpp (smack and openfire) get registration state of group of users?

Tags: android, openfire, smack

I use openfire and smack for presence management in my app.
I use phone number as username and wanna get list of registered users that exist in user device contacts list.
Is there any way to check user**s** registration state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine registered users (just like Whatsapp) you can simply post contact's of user on your server and there you can check which contacts exist in your users table (the table where you keep the entry of new user with his phone number).        Based on that data you can reply to your application with those phone numbers which are registered on your service and they can be shown to user in mobile app.

Comment: Hi,I want do this with xmpp only , but if it impossible with xmpp I will try your suggest,thanks.