# Openfire Sync Phone Contact To Know register Users

Tags: ios, swift, xmpp, openfire

I use openfire server and from iOS client I get the phoneNumber for username to register user . Now I want to sync contact phone of user to know which user contact is registered on the server. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xmpp (smack and openfire) get registration state of group of users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40956415/xmpp-smack-and-openfire-get-registration-state-of-group-of-users)

Comment: Thank you for your replay but if there any more explanation it will be better , how i post the contact to openfire server and how we can check if the users exist and add them to the user roster... thank you

Comment: You can not post contacts to Openfire Server, instead you will have to develop an HTTP service in whatever server side language you are comfortable with.
Upon signup, you can post all contacts of user to your service, and in that service, you can query Openfire database ''ofUser' table to check if any of the contact exists there, and in this way you can identify registered users in user contacts.